# Limit Network access but allow a specific IP for a Running Docker Container

Tags: docker

I try to use a docker container where only a specific IP address should be accessible out of the running container.
iptables are only working in priviliged docker container. But than the user can change the iptables themselves.
A nice idea would be to create a docker image with a dockerfile and with iptables. But there is no option for privileged right while creating an image.
Anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

Best

Comment: Create iptables on the host (in the `FORWARD` chain), not inside the Docker container.

Comment: But how can I handle different IPs for different docker instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each docker container has a unique IP address, so if you want to permit a container with address 172.17.0.21 and you want it to be able to *only* access address 8.8.8.8, you could do something like:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.17.0.21 -d 8.8.8.8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.17.0.21 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

It is also possible to modify the iptables rules *inside* an unprivileged container using the `nsenter` command.  For example, if you start a Docker container:

```
docker run --name example -d myimage
```

You can get the PID of that container like this:

```
pid=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' example)
```

And then use `nsenter` to run commands inside that container's network namespace:

```
nsenter -t $pid -n iptables ...
```

These commands will run *without* the capabilities restrictions of commands run inside the container.

Comment: Using nsenter to add iptables rules looks nice. Any hints on how to make such rules persistent / reinstated on container startup?

Comment: I don't think there's a great way to make this persistent.  The best you could do without too much effort would be to put all the necessary commands in a script so you only have to run a single command to re-instate things.